# Include Id in Query Output used in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to include Id which I am using in WHERE clause of my query. Please find my query below:-

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1,'A')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(2,'B')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(3,'C')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(4,'E')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(5,'E')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(6,'F')

SELECT * FROM @Table1

SELECT dbo.MyAgg(ID) AS Ids
FROM @Table1 T                              
WHERE T.NAME <> 'E'       
AND T.ID  <=5
```

The output it shows is:-

```
1,2,3
```

But desired output is:-

```
1,2,3,5
```

Thanks,

Rahul

Comment: How is it possible? You want to include ID=5 but not ID=4 with the same condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT ID AS Ids
  FROM Table1 T                              
 WHERE T.NAME <> 'E'       
   AND T.ID  <=5
UNION
SELECT ID AS Ids
  FROM Table1 T
 WHERE T.ID = 5
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/985f2/3)

Answer (score 1):

You sholud remove `T.NAME <> 'E'` condition

```
select dbo.MyAgg(ID)AS Ids
from @Table1 T                              
where T.ID  <=5
```

Comment: I need to put that condition as it is requirement, it is possible that name may be repeated

Comment: @rahulaggarwal Why `5` should display and `4` not ?

Comment: It is my applications requirement

Comment: @rahulaggarwal Can you describe the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the condition from your query

```
 where T.NAME <> 'E'
```

Because it remove the 5th id field record from result set.That's why you are not getting 5 id in result.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to use an OR rather than a union:

```
SELECT dbo.MyAgg(ID) AS Ids
FROM @Table1 T                              
WHERE (T.NAME <> 'E' OR T.ID = 5)       
AND T.ID  <= 5
```